# Use standard keybindings for copy, paste, cut, etc. as in other software?

Tags: key-bindings, cua-mode

I want to use the same basic keybindings for copy (`C-c`), paste (`C-v`), cut (`C-x`), etc. that are supported in some other software.

How can I do that?

Comment: For cut, copy & paste there's `cua-mode`.

Comment: cua? What is that?

Comment: [`CUA`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/CUA-Bindings.html) stands for "Common User Access" and allows you to use `C-c`, `C-v`, `C-x`, and `C-z` as you would in other programs (see also the [EmacsWiki page](http://www.emacswiki.org/CuaMode)). @paprika: do you want to convert your comment to an answer?

Comment: @Dan: I don't have time for that currently.  I was sure that someone else would mention `cua-mode` as part of an answer anyway.  And TaylanUB did. :-)

Comment: Oh thank the gods, or just Dan four years ago... I didn't know I'd stumbled across and installed CUA mode while scratching around in some emacs rabbit hole or something and now was sorely missing my `scroll-up-command` and `scroll-down-command` -- thank you!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As others commented, `cua-mode` does this, which ships with Emacs. Just `M-x cua-mode RET` to enable it, or put `(cua-mode 1)` in your `.emacs` or `.emacs.d/init.el` to enable it at startup.

Unless it changed in 24.4, it will also enable using `DEL` (usually backspace) to delete (without cutting) a selected region, simply starting to type to overwrite (without cutting) a selected region, and holding down Shift and navigating to select a region, just like all "normal" text editing software does. Possibly some of this functionality has been split up in 24.4; looking into the [Emacs manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/index.html) should tell you.

Answer (score 3):

You also might want to check out ergoemacs mode, https://ergoemacs.github.io/. It remaps emacs keybindings to ones that make more sense to users acclimated to modern editing software, among many other changes.

Comment: Note that `ergoemacs-mode` is in GNU ELPA, so you can install it directly via `M-x package-list`.